# Installing Lubuntu on Asus EEE

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, bios

I have an old Asus EEE Netbook with 512 MB RAM and 4GB internal harddisk. Currently it has Ubuntu 10.04 installed, with one problem: I forgot the root password.

I installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a stick using Unetbootin, and want to startup from that, but it refuses to do so. I enter the boot menu, set the first harddisk to the stick, but it keeps booting from the internal disk.

When pressing the shift keys continuesly at startup, I see "Grub menu" appearing, but no menu, and after that Ubuntu just starts up.

Entering Grub using the Esc of Shift key at startup doesn't enter the Grub menu.

**Do you know what method I can use to either reset the root password, or startup from the external usb stick?**

Comment: Did you test your USB key on another computer?

Comment: What exactly is "I installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a stick"? Have you used the USB creator from 10.04?

Comment: I used Unetbootin on my Mac to create a Live stick with Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The ASUS EeePC recognizes the flash drive as another hard drive so when you boot it select F2 to get into the BIOS.  You will have to move the flash drive (which is under hard drive) ahead of your internal hard drive.  Then just save and continue with the boot.  The computer will then boot from the flash.